# ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory locking file(s) briefly on large zip files?

Tags: c#

I have a 110MB zip file that I am extracting using `ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory`. After I extract the zip file, I use `Directory.Move` to rename the folder. However, when calling `Directory.Move` I get permission denied exception for access to the folder where the zip file was originally extracted. If I add a short delay, like 500ms, `Directory.Move` works.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, dest, true); //Extract zip file to destination
Directory.Move(dest, newName); //Rename folder; newName is full path and does not exist
```

The above code works fine for smaller zip files, like 10MB.
The below consistently works for larger file sizes:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zip, dest, true); //Extract zip file to destination
Thread.Sleep(500)
Directory.Move(dest, newName); //Rename folder; newName is full path and does not exist
```

Why do larger files requiring a short delay between extracting and moving? Is there a more robust way to do this other than just add a delay?

Comment: Sounds like a virus scanner triggering on new files and preventing you from changing the path of said files until it's done scanning everything (but verifying this would require something like ProcMon). If that's the case there's not a whole lot you can do, besides a retry loop, or else extracting the file to the correct destination to begin with.

Comment: You could [try to find out by C# code which process is locking a file](https://pastebin.com/4CkkHd3f) and then see whether @JeroenMostert's assumption is true (I guess it is).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, I suspect that is it!